# Find generators of the ideal of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

The following exercise comes from Fulton's Algebraic Curves:

> Let $k$ be an infinite field and $V = \{(t,t^2,t^3) \, ; \, t \in k \} \subset \mathbb{A}^3(k)$. Show that $V$ is algebraic and compute $I(V)$ by giving a finite set of generators.

Now, showing $V$ is algebraic is easy by noting that $V = V(X^2-Y, X^3-Z)$, but I can't find a way to describe $I(V)$ explicitly. Obviously $(X^2-Y)(X^3-Z) \in V$, but how can I find the actual generators of this ideal?

Comment: What about $X^2-Y$ and $X^3-Z$ as themselves. You just need to show they are generators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideal is generated by $y-x^2$ and $z-x^3$ for assume that $f(x,y,z) \in I$ that is $$f(t,t^2,t^3)=0$$ identically. We need to show that $$f \in(y-x^2,z-x^3)$$ now since our generators are linear in $y$ and $z$ we can subtract multiples of these to reduce to case where $f$ does not contain the variables $y$ or $z$. But the the assumption becomes that $f(t)=0$ identically. So we are done.

Comment: This sounds perfect to me, but where did you use the fact that the field is infinite? If it was not would there be any trouble in "clearing" the terms with $y$ and $z$?

Comment: In the last step, $x^p-x=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ but its not the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Rene has given a perfectly fine answer to your question.

Here is another approach that works when $k$ is algebraically closed (I realize that the assumption is a little weaker: you only assume that $k$ is infinite). Let $X=\{(t, t^2, t^3): t\in k\}$ to denote your algebraic set.  You already know that $X=V(y-x^2, z-x^3)$. Then, by Nullstellensatz, $I(X) =I(V(y-x^2, z-x^3)) = \sqrt{(y-x^2, z-x^3)}$ where I am using the notation $\sqrt{J}$ to denote the radical of the ideal $J$. But note that $(y-x^2, z-x^3)$ is a prime ideal. Indeed, the quotient ring
$$
k[x, y, z]/(y-x^2, z-x^3] \cong k[x, y]/(y-x^2) \cong k[x]
$$
is an integral domain. Here we used (twice!) the fact $R[t]/(t-a)\cong R$. Since $(y-x^2, z-x^3)$ is prime, it is in particular a radical ideal, i.e.  $\sqrt{(y-x^2, z-x^3)} = (y-x^2, z-x^3)$. Thus, $I(X)=(y-x^2, z-x^3)$.