# Dimension of Cubic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ be the set $Y=\{(t,t^2,t^3) \}$.

Show that dim $Y =1$.

To do so, I have to reveal what is the closed set of $Y$.

Please give me a hint.

This differs the [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258420/find-generators-of-the-ideal-of-an-algebraic-set), in which the ideal are discussed. However I want to consider the dimension. To do so, I need the sequence of irreducible distinct closed subset $Z_1 \subset Z_2 \subset ...$

Comment: What do **you** mean by "the closed set of Y"?  In the usual topology, Y **is** a closed set.  Also what is "$A^3$"?  If t is a real number, I would have expected "$R^3$.

Comment: $\mathbb A^3$ is an affine space. Note the Algebraic Geometry tag.

Comment: To answer the OP's question, one can show that the coordinate ring is isomorphic to $k[x]$. Let me know if you want me to flesh out the answer.

Comment: $k[x,y,z]]/(y-x^2,z-x^3) = k[x,x^2,x^3] =k[x]$ and the dimension of $Y$ is the dimension of the affine coordinate ring $A(Y)$, which is one.  Thus the dimension of $Y$ is also one.